# Restricting user input in Sting

Tags: java

I'm trying to restrict the user input in this code, so depending on the choice either "D##" or "E##" are allowed. How should I formulate the condition?

```
System.out.println("Please choose one of the following options: ");
System.out.println("1. ");
System.out.println("2. ");
while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("You have entered an invalid input. Please choose between options 1 and 2");
    scanner.nextLine();
}
choice = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine();
if (choice == 1) {
    System.out.println("Enter an ID of the type D##");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    if (input.equals("D" + "[0-9]{2}")) {
        System.out.println("Nice");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }
    break;
} else if (choice == 2) {
    System.out.println("Enter an ID of the type E##");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    if (input == "E[0-9]{2}") {
        System.out.println("Nice");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid input. Please choose between options 1 and 2");
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you facing the problem? Is the first if condition working as expected or not? Also if you could provide what is the behaviour you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [java.lang.String.matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) instead of `==` or `equals`.

> **matches**
>
> `public boolean matches(String regex)`
>
> Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression.
>   An invocation of this method of the form `str.matches(regex)` yields exactly the same result as the expression `Pattern.matches(regex, str)`
>
> Parameters:
>   `regex` - the regular expression to which this string is to be matched
>
> Returns:
>   `true` if, and only if, this string matches the given regular expression
>
> Throws:
>   `PatternSyntaxException` - if the regular expression's syntax is invalid
>
> Since:
>   1.4
>
> See Also:
>   `Pattern`